# PHP 7.2 to PHP 7.4 upgrade String Validation Creating a Server Performance Issue

Tags: php, laravel, performance

My Website is based on the Laravel Framework 5.5.50 and After upgrading from PHP 7.2 to PHP 7.4, it had a very strange issue as explained below,

When executing below code in PHP 7.4 if the number of rows returned are greater than 150 it crashes with a Internal Server Error with a Timeout, however if its only return rows < 100 it works fine. But it all worked well in PHP 7.2 for any number of rows.

```php
$appointments = Appointment::whereHas('info', function ($query) use ($year) {
    $year = $year ? $year : date('Y');
    $query->whereBetween('appointment_year', [($year - 1), ($year + 1)]);
})
    ->with(['info', 'case'])
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->skip(0)
    ->take(100)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

foreach($appointments as $k => &$appointment) {

    /**
     * This is where the problem is as I found out later
     * Whats wrong with this check ?
     *
     * As I understand, it is looking if the name is not null
     */

    if (!$appointment['customer']['name']) {
        unset($appointment[$k]);
        continue;
    }

    $appointment['customer']['name'] = Crypt::decrypt($appointment['customer']['name']);
}

echo json_encode(array_values($appointments));
```

After doing some research and debugging on the issue, I found if I change the above code `String` validation to check the name to below code, it just works fine even with `1000+` rows.

```php
if (!isset($appointment['customer']['name']) || empty($appointment['customer']['name'])) {
    unset($appointment[$k]);
    continue;
}
```

Question is does anyone has any idea what could be the root cause of this issue?

Because both codes look pretty valid to me. Is there something unknown that creates this crash when using the `(!$variable name)`? Or this may have been throwing hidden errors slowing down the processing on the server? Or something else?

I am just curious to find out, if anyone can share any insight into this it will be great for everyone.

Comment: I am not sure what to say, but can I ask if you have a typo here `foreach($appointments $k => &$appointment) {` ? You did not write it like `foreach($appointments as $k => &$appointment) {`?

Comment: !$appointment['customer']['name'] will throw a "Undefined array key" warning if those keys don't exist on $appointment. isset will return true if keys exist and value is not null

Comment: Also unset($appointment[$k]); should be unset($appointments[$k]);. With my previous comment and the one by @matiaslauriti I can tell you that the code you provided does not work on PHP 7.2 or 7.4.  (if you've changed your PHP version you should check your logs and error reporting settings - all issues mentioned should throw warnings and errors).

Comment: @kpoz I think the `unset` will still work because he is passing the variable as `reference` instead of `value` (author is using `&`). But still, not very readable code.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Looks like a bug since $k is the key from $appointments and would unset a different thing in $appointment over each iteration.

Comment: @kopz oh, you are right ! my bad there

Comment: Is customer a relation to Appointment, if so, you're lazy loading the relation for each result.

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes its typo, i just added it,

Comment: @Tropus yeah customer is related to Appointment.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Did you check whether the PHP settings are the same? Did the code run equally long using PHP 7.2 (maybe you've remove the max_execution_time on updating?)?

Comment: @NicoHaase same settings, in php.ini however we moved to php-fpm in the new server, if that is important

Answer (score 1):

```php
if (!$appointment['customer']['name']) { // can trigger E_NOTICE
```

There might be an expensive error handler being called for this notice.

```php
if (empty(appointment['customer']['name'])) { // does not trigger errors
```

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding that you have missed `as` in your `foreach` (that should throw a fatal error, so it is a typo here), I will tell you that having any version of PHP, that code is not performant in any way.

Let me explain:
You are using `->take(100)` so you are limiting the results to as much as `100` results and no more, so you are "safe" in that case, but for anyone reading this, even if you have `100` results, it could be instantiating a lot of models behind scenes, it depends a lot in your App.

So, to fix any performance issues (in this case) you can take advantage of the database super fast processing/filtering, how so ? Compare your code with mine (doing exactly the same thing):

```php
$appointments = Appointment::with(['info', 'case', 'customer'])
    ->whereHas('info', function (Builder $query) use ($year) {
        $year = $year ? $year : date('Y');

        return $query->whereBetween('appointment_year', [($year - 1), ($year + 1)]);
    })
    ->whereHas('customer', function (Builder $query) {
        return $query->whereNotNull('name');
    })
    ->orderByDesc('id')
    ->limit(100)
    ->get();

$appointments->transform(function (Appointment $appointment) {
    $appointment->customer->name = Crypt::decrypt($appointment->customer->name);

    return $appointment;
});

return json_encode(array_values($appointments->toArray()));
```

See that I replaced your `foreach` with a `transform` but I totally removed your `string` check and moved it to the database itself. This way is way more performant, if you run both codes, yours should take a little bit less time executing DB query but will consume more memory, mine will just take a little bit more time executing DB query but less memory (or same) will be used but it should average take less time.

I also changed your `foreach` for a `transform`, meaning that I will change each result, in-memory instead of creating a new result and then deleting old one from memory (that would happen if you use `map`), in this case it could still be performant having `map` or `transform`, but remember `transform` is literally changing the value from the object, so you cannot manipulate it like `save` or anything else because you are going to save the `unencrypted` data (this is why you use `API Resources` so you map your results to what you want instead of doing this).

And one last **super major** change, you are taking/limiting your results to `100`, but let's say all your results have the condition that `customer.name = null`, so you end up with `0` results. In my case, if the first `100` results has this condition, but the next `1000` not, then I would always get exactly `100` results with `customer.name = not null`. Have that in mind !

Comment: Good points. If performance really is an issue here one might even go a step further and refrain from creating copies of `$appointments` for the output.
Emitting the brackets and commas for the array and calling `json_encode` on each element. One could even avoid fetching the whole result set from database before returning anything and instead pass through each entry.